# How to call AJAX in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to fetch MySQL table  (custom table) data to my admin panel via AJAX. When user click the button get data without page refresh. 
I already created it on PHP but where to add AJAX file in WordPress?

This is my code. Note I am trying to make plugin When user click fetchdata button call the AJAX for result.
I added JS file in my plugin

I called js from main plugin file

```
function school_register_head()  {
    $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
    $url2 = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/jquery-1.3.2.js';
    $url3 = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/script.js';

    echo "<script src=$url2 type=text/javascript></script>\n";  
    echo "<script src=$url3 type=text/javascript></script>\n"; 
}
add_action('admin_head', 'school_register_head');
```

script.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#display").click(function() {          
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "display.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
});
```

display.php file

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT postid from `wp_school_post`");
echo "<table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><tr>";
foreach ($rows as $row ){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row->postid</td>";
    echo "</tr>";}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

html button

```
<input type="button" id="display" class="button" value="Fetch All Data" onClick="fetch_data();" />
 <div id="responsecontainer" align="center">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "where to put the AJAX file" means how to include it to the admin page: The easiest way would be to use `admin_enqueue_scripts()`, for example, if you're implementing it in a theme:

```
<?php    
    function load_ajax_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script("ajax-script", get_template_directory() . "/scripts/ajax-script.js");
    }
    add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", "load_ajax_script");
?>
```

Add this code to your functions.php within the active theme directory.

Next step would be the **jQuery script**. Open the .js script file used with `wp_enqueue_script()` and add the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#fetch-data").click(function() {
        var script_url = "http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/display.php";
        var response_container = jQuery("#responsecontainer");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:script_url,
            success:function(response) {
                response_container.html(response);
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("There was an error while fetching the data.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note that **you have to use a URL** when calling the .php file, not the absolute path on the server as you would when using PHP's `include()`. Depending on where you put the script, use either `$(...)` or `jQuery(...)`.

Now we have to **insert the button** that is calling AJAX and of course the **container** where the returned content is being inserted. Since you didn't say where it is being displayed, I just put it in the top of the admin area for now:

```
function display_ajax_button() {
    ?>
    <input type="button" value="Fetch data" id="fetch-data" />
    <div id="fetched-data-content"></div>
<?php
}
add_action("admin_init", "display_ajax_button");
```

Finally, we **create the PHP script itself**. I've just copied your code and saved it in the same directory as defined in the `jQuery.ajax()` `URL` parameter:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT postid from `wp_school_post`");
echo "<table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><tr>";
foreach ($rows as $row ){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row->postid</td>";
    echo "</tr>";}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

That should be the simpliest approach. Open the admin page and give it a try. Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Not working i think i make mistake where to put the code :(

this is on local server not live site.

Comment: i cant place anycode in function php because i want to build plugin so i want all code in plugin folder.

Comment: please explain me where to place i am beginner

Comment: I think I have explained it in detail already, haven't I? The code I used for my example can't be copied and pasted, you have to make some minor changes according to your setup. Give me a few minutes, I'll give an example file.

Comment: Alright, I've just written a very simple plugin that contains a menu page with a button which gets some posts. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B581Nph7ZvaQWko0Q3c3anV3Y0U/edit?usp=sharing Move the folder into you /plugins/ directory, activate it and navigat to "AJAX Example" within the admin area. See comments in the code files for more descriptions.

Comment: AWESOME Brother you save my life :) hearty thanx working good actually i'm beginner so i ask question Thank you AGAIN